# How to use BitmapRegionDecoder in android 2.2 and lower

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to use BitmapRegionDecoder class in my application to handle very large images. My application is developing under android 2.2 (API-8), but BitmapRegionDecoder is not available in android 2.2 and lower and i can't change android 2.2 to 2.3 or higher, it must be android 2.2 only. So is there any other way to use BitmapRegionDecoder in my application or any jar file for BitmapRegionDecoder or alternative jar to BitmapRegionDecoder that perform same task of BitmapRegionDecoder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use BitmapRegionDecoder code in android 2.2.2 (Froyo)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035169/how-can-i-use-bitmapregiondecoder-code-in-android-2-2-2-froyo)

Answer (score 0):

I've read in the description of [this project](https://github.com/johnnylambada/WorldMap#readme), that the recreation of the BitmapRegionDecoder for API < 10 requires heavy use of JNI:

> on SO, Dianne Hackborn says this is non trivial.

So you could try it, but I fear it will be just too complicated to port it back to lower versions :(

Edit: I just found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035169/how-can-i-use-bitmapregiondecoder-code-in-android-2-2-2-froyo), maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [my other (detailed) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31523069/2760919) about **`BitmapRegionDecoderCompat`** (API 8+).

Comment: Just vote to close similar questions as duplicates instead of duplicating (or referencing) your answer.