# Any alternative way to achieve BitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(...) android 2.2 and below?

Tags: android, bitmap, crop, region, decoder

I am using BitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(...) to crop image. But it does not work for android 2.3.1 (api level 10 ) and below. Please let me know is there any alternative way to achieve this. Even android-support-v4.jar library does not contain this class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use BitmapRegionDecoder code in android 2.2.2 (Froyo)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035169/how-can-i-use-bitmapregiondecoder-code-in-android-2-2-2-froyo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to crop an image. It's been around since always, so provides an alternative for older APIs.

The documentation is pretty self-explanatory:

> Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source
>   bitmap. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may
>   have been made. It is initialized with the same density as the
>   original bitmap.
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> source    The bitmap we are subsetting
> x         The x coordinate of the first pixel in source
> y         The y coordinate of the first pixel in source
> width     The number of pixels in each row
> height    The number of rows
> ```
>
> Returns A copy of a subset of the source bitmap or the source bitmap
>   itself.