# Displaying pictures with a big width in android app

Tags: java, android, scrollview, drawable, timeline

I'm currently doing an app for a museum, and into this app, there have to be a timeline. I made the timeline into a jpg file.
I am trying to display this file (picture 1993x239 px) in an imageView, which is into a Scrollview, however :

- on my phone LG optimus L3 (e400) it works quite well
- on my Nexus 7 tablet, the picture don't appear

how can I do to make it work ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/frise"
        android:src="@drawable/frise" />
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518215/display-huge-images-in-android

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It would work for me, however I need my app to work on API 8 and above, and your link uses BitmapRegionDecoder which is for API 10+

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035169/how-can-i-use-bitmapregiondecoder-code-in-android-2-2-2-froyo

Comment: I tried with BitmapRegionDecoder with Api 10, to see if I was able to display the picture, but it's still not the case. The code on your first link is not working for me, even with high values of "k". And I really want to avoid SampleSize because it decreases the picture's quality. But still, thanks for your answer :)