# How to handle outofmemory exception in android?

Tags: android, image, memory, bitmap, out-of-memory

I had a look for outofmemory exception questions but I couldn't find out a way for my problem. I have an application which processes images. I need to get RGB values of each pixel of the image. I can do it when I choose image from whatsapp file because they have small size but if I want to choose images from gallery(taken via camera) or if I want to take photo from camera directly I have outofmemeory exception. I don't want to scale down image because I need all pixels' information of the image.

I have the file and name information of the image as a string, I get this exception when I decode the string as shown below;

```
imgDecodableString  = intent3.getStringExtra("BMP");
rotatedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
```

Is there any way to handle this problem?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html

Comment: Make sure you are not leaking memory regardless of how big the bitmap is: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html

Comment: imgDecodableString is the base64 string?

Comment: Duh, use less RAM :)

Comment: you can load portions at a time - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753013/how-to-load-tiles-from-a-large-bitmap-in-android

Answer (score 1):

If You use this line of code in Manifest file in application tag the Outofmemory exception will solve try this.

android:largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to scale down the image, you can use [BitmapRegionDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) to decode each part of the image and process the bitmap instead of decode whole the image.

Answer (score 0):

you must convert the high resolution of your drawable image to: **drawable-xxhdpi**. 
and add: **android:largeHeap="true" on androidManifest.xml inside application tag**

I have solved my OutOfMemory problem by using this method