# Bitmap getWith() and getHeighth() always return same size?

Tags: android, android-camera, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

I want to rotate bitmap when the picture taken as potrait . 
I want to understand image is potrait or lanscape? 
I use this code :

```
   Bitmap  photo   = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_img,options); 
   int imageHeight = photo.getHeight();
   int imageWidth  = photo.getWidth();
```

When I take image as portroit and lanscape it does not matter it is always like this :
imageHeight =390; imageWidth =520;

How can I understand a picture is taken lanscape or portrait.

Thanks

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286714/android-get-orientation-of-a-camera-bitmap-and-rotate-back-90-degrees

Comment: I do not understand that question it is too complex

Comment: You probably want to read the [Exif information](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) of the bitmap in order to find out its orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code taken from nigels link and altered it for the provided code snippet

```
Bitmap  photo   = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_img,options);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path_img);
int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);  
int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
if (rotation != 0f) {
    matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
}

Bitmap adjustedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {        
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; } 
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; } 
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }            
    return 0;    
}
```

from what i understood, this code snippet and the 2 methods should do all the work by themselfs.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I understand a picture is taken lanscape or portrait?

assuming the image is currently stored on file, you can get it orientation from the Exif metadata object:

```
File f = new File(capturedImageFilePath);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

note that this information not necessarily available - it's up to the application which captured the image to store this metadata on the file.

in case this information not exists, `getAttributeInt` would return `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL`

the orientation can can be one of the following: `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90` / `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180` / `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270`