# Android Camera Landscape Image

Tags: android, camera

I'm developing an app which has a SurfaceView with a camera. I want to take landscape images in both landscape and portrait modes. The preview is shown okay since I used `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` in my code.

However when I take the image, it is displayed rotated. I can rotate it again but it will become portrait as soon as it is done. Does anyone know how to take a landscape image from camera?

This is how I configured the camera parameters

```
     private void configure() {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

        // Configure image format. RGB_565 is the most common format.
        List<Integer> formats = params.getSupportedPictureFormats();
        if (formats.contains(PixelFormat.RGB_565))
            params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
        else
            params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);

        // Choose the biggest picture size supported by the hardware
        /*List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(sizes.size()-1);
        params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);*/
        params.setPictureSize(Constants.IMAGE_WIDTH, Constants.IMAGE_HEIGHT);

        List<String> flashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (flashModes.size() > 0)
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

        // Action mode take pictures of fast moving objects
        List<String> sceneModes = params.getSupportedSceneModes();
        if (sceneModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_ACTION))
            params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_ACTION);
        else
            params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);

        // if you choose FOCUS_MODE_AUTO remember to call autoFocus() on
        // the Camera object before taking a picture 
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        camera.setParameters(params);
    }
```

And this is where I take the image

```
    private void takePicture()
    {
        configure();
        camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, pictureCallback_RAW, pictureCallback_JPEG);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is where I save the image which is taken from the camera

```
     PictureCallback pictureCallback_JPEG = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File storageDirectory = CameraHelper.getStorageDirectory();
            String fileName = CameraHelper.getStorageFileName();

            imagePath = storageDirectory.getPath()+File.separator+fileName;
            File output = new File(storageDirectory, fileName);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                imageCapturedState=true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

This is the camera preview when I take the picture

[image]

This is how it is displayed once it is saved (The image in the preview is rotated 90 degrees.)

[image]

So as you see, I can rotate the image, but it will become portrait once I have done it. How can I save a landscape image without ratating? Thank you!

Comment: change the image roation when u show image

Comment: I can do that, But that will convert the landscape image to a portrait one. Is there a way to keep the landscape dimensions and save it as landscape image without rotating?

Comment: i think u r using samsung mobile bydefulat all mobile camera is landscape

Comment: Yes, But when the image is saved it is rotated. Can I know how to avoid this?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286714/android-get-orientation-of-a-camera-bitmap-and-rotate-back-90-degrees