# Using exif to rotate an image

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, exif

i was following this link [Android get Orientation of a camera Bitmap? And rotate back -90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286714/android-get-orientation-of-a-camera-bitmap-and-rotate-back-90-degrees) to rotate my image if/when necessary, but its not working for me, i get this error

05-28 23:29:30.049 9735-9735/ss.sealstudios.com.socialstories E/JHEAD: can't open '/document/508'

but checking it like below looks like there pointing in the right place

05-28 23:29:30.049 9735-9735/ss.sealstudios.com.socialstories I/System.out: bitmap uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/508 0

//the 0 on the end is me checking for the rotation

i was wondering if this was build version specific like getting the real path from a URI as running this code on my marshmallow device gives me an entirely different result (this result, ie: error codes, is from a kitkat device), but this has defeated me for some weeks now following all sorts of answers to no avail, can anyone weigh in and help me please, here's what I'm trying to do

```
   if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data 
   != null 
   && data.getData() != null) 
  {

        Uri uri = data.getData();


        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new 
            BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = (int) 4;
            InputStream inputStream = 
            getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, 
            null, bitmapOptions);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
            int rotation = 
            exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,  
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
            System.out.println("bitmap uri " + uri + " " + rotation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            if (rotation != 0f){
                matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
                Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 
                0,scaledBitmap.getWidth(),scaledBitmap.getHeight(), 
                matrix, true);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);

            }else
                imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { 
    return 90; 
    }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {   
    return 180; }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  
    return 270; }
    return 0;
}
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
```

This will not work. If you call `getPath()` on a `Uri`, you are doing it wrong, as that is meaningless for most `Uri` values, particularly those with a `content` scheme, as your has.

Since the SDK's `ExifInterface` only works with local files, you will need other EXIF code. I use [some code from the AOSP for this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/tree/master/cam2/src/main/java/com/android/mms). That version of `ExifInterface` can work with an `InputStream`, so you can get a fresh `InputStream` for the content identified by the `Uri` and pass that to the alternative `ExifInterface`.

Comment: I've just looked at the link how are you using that exf interface Java file?

Comment: @MartinSeal: See https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/master/cam2/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/cam2/ImageContext.java for where I use it.