# Bitmap received from camera has wrong orientation / rotated

Tags: java, android, camera, imageview

I am using Camera intent to capture a photo on android, when intent from onActivityResult returns bitmap it has wrong orientation on some phones.
I know there are ways to fix this,but all the solutions I have seen talk about image stored in file.
What I am retrieving from intent is directly bitmap image. I want to know how I can get exif data of a bitmap and then correct its orientation. I repeat I have seen answers which deal with file and not bitmap, so please consider this before down voting.

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constants.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
 }
```

And result is as follows

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

How to get orientation and rotate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android)

Comment: @MikelPascual that question doest specify how to get exif of a bitmap that's what I have said in op

Comment: You can see this [response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11081918/5061288), i think it's helpful.

Comment: @DzMobNadjib nope that's not what I want

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Exif is a file format that inserts some information data to JPEG.
https://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html

And `Bitmap` is data structior data holds row pixel data, no exif info.
So I think it is impossible to get exif info from `Bitmap`.
There is no method to get exif info.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

**ORIGINAL**

I agree with @DzMobNadjib .
I think the info of rotation is only in exif.
To take exif, I recommend you to take following steps.

**1. Start camera activity with file path.**

See *[Save the Full-size Photo]* capture of [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPat).

You can start the camera activity with file path.The camera activity will save the image to the file path that you passed.

**2. In 'onActivityResult', Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286714/android-get-orientation-of-a-camera-bitmap-and-rotate-back-90-degrees/11081918#11081918)** (as @DzMobNadjib suggested)

Your code will be like this:
(Sorry I'm not tested. Please read carefuly and follow the above answer)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = getAdjustedBitmap(uri);
        }
    }
}

private Bitmap getAdjustedBitmap(Uri uri) {
    FileInputStream is = null;
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());

        int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (rotation != 0f) {
            matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
        }

        is = new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getPath()));
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        int width = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
        int height = sourceBitmap.getHeight();

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My question is can I get the exif info from bitmap