# Android || Rotation of Bitmap Image

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory

Please suggest me the way to rotate the bitmap image in android.

I have following sample but when I rotate the image with 10 degrees it gets black at corners as well as size of image is increased.

When i rotate image continuously with 10 degrees it throw memory out of bound exception.

```
private void rotateImage(String sourcePath, float angle) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sourcePath);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(angle);
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    File file = new File(sourcePath);
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        rotated.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        bitmap.recycle();
        rotated.recycle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: add line in your menifest activity tag:    androidl:LargeHeap=true;

Comment: What is your goal? Maybe you can use a ObjectAnimator, if you only want to rotate an image on your view.

Comment: My goal is to make image rotating app.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) for image rotation

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286714/android-get-orientation-of-a-camera-bitmap-and-rotate-back-90-degrees#answer-11081918) solution for details, how to use ExifInterface

See more info about [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif)