# How to set bitmap to intent in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Bitmap from an Uri [android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879992/get-bitmap-from-an-uri-android)

How to set bitmap to intent?

I have bitmap as input and I need to call `Intent.setData()`.
`Intent.setData()` expects `Uri`, How to convert `bitmap` to `Uri`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't it easier to store image and attech its address to intent?

Answer (score 0):

hey just simply you can pass bitmap using **putExtra()**

see in following example

```
Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
it.putExtra("bitmap",bp);
startActivity(it);
```

and for getting bitmap from intent use following

```
Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().get("bitmap");
```

Enjoy..!