# How to avoid extra height of background drawable in a relative layout?

Tags: android, background, android-relativelayout, drawable

I am using a relative layout with height as wrap content . When i put a large drawable as its background,instead of taking the child height,the relative layout takes the height of the drawable,which is added as background. When i use color,there is no problem in height of the layout. How i can avoid the extra height of the background image?

Comment: Please post the drawable file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8292110/1777090. You would need to make images of correct size.

Comment: @ZInj It is an image drawable,not a xml drawable

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18312414/3602047

Comment: You need to maintain separate drawables

Answer (score 0):

```
int width = child.getwidth(); 
int height = child.getheight();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
myRelativelayout.setLayoutParams(parms);
```