# Out of memory Error when previewing image in android

Tags: android

I have a custom camera application. When capture a image the application crashes. It should look like when capture then the image will preview on the screen but it crashes(Out of memory error). There are two activity (one is CustomCamera activity with two buttons and Preview activity with two buttons).

Here is my CustomCameraActivity:

```
public class CustomCameraActivity extends Activity implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = this;

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mOrientaion1 = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgError);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    Button btn1 = (Button) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    Button btn2 = (Button) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.Button02);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "1111111111111111111111111",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

            Constant.rotationValueForCamera = Constant.rotationValue;
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "22222222222222222222222222",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("0 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");

            Constant.imagePickerStatus = 0;

            Log.e("0 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");

            finish();
        }
    });

    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

    int ot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == ot) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.e("ori1111", "land");
    } else {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("ori111", "port");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        findViewById(R.id.Button01).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.Button02).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.e("ori", "land");
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        findViewById(R.id.Button01).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.Button02).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("ori", "port");
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    if (Constant.isCapturedOk) {
        Constant.isCapturedOk = false;

        finish();
    }

}

PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Log.e("Camrera", "22222222222222222");

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PreviewActivity.class);
        // intent.putExtra("data", data);
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                data.length);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (Constant.result == 180) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        if (Constant.result == 270) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        }
        int height = bitmapPicture.getHeight();
        int width = bitmapPicture.getWidth();
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapPicture,
                height, width, true);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);

        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
        byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
        Constant.imageData = bitmapdata;
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    if (previewing) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
    }

    if (camera != null) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
            setCameraDisplayOrientation(this,cameraId,camera);
            previewing = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
        int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        Constant.result = 0;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        Constant.result = 90;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        Constant.result = 180;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        degrees = 270;
        Constant.result = 270;
        break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Log.e("Tab", "Stoping");
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        return true;

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

}

Here is my Preview Activity:

```
 public class PreviewActivity extends Activity {

Context context;
Button btnRetake, btnOk;
// byte[] data;
ImageView imgPreview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.preview_layout);

    context = this;

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

    btnRetake = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1FromPreviw);
    btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2FromPreviw);

    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgImagePreview);

    // Intent myIntent = getIntent();

    // data = myIntent.getExtras().getByteArray("data");

    Drawable image = null;
    image = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            Constant.imageData, 0, Constant.imageData.length));
    imgPreview.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
    // image = new BitmapDrawable(Constant.imageData);
    // imgPreview.setBackgroundDrawable(image);

    btnRetake.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Constant.isCapturedOk = false;

            finish();
        }
    });

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SaveImage();
        }
    });

}

private void SaveImage() {
    /*
     * File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(); if (pictureFile == null) {
     * Log.e("Camrera", "nullllllllllllllllll"); return; }
     */
    try {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Constant.imageData , 0, Constant.imageData.length);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG ,50 , stream);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "data"
                + File.separator + context.getPackageName()
                + File.separator + "files" + File.separator + "image.jpg");

        Log.e("pa", file.getPath() + "  :  " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e("len", stream.size() + "");

        file.createNewFile();

        /*
         * Log.e("Camrera", "yesssssssssssssssssss"); Log.e("Camrera",
         * pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
         */
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(stream.toByteArray());
        fos.close();

        Log.e("Camrera", "great");

        Constant.isCapturedOk = true;

        Log.e("1 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");

        Constant.imagePickerStatus = 1;

        Log.e("1 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");

        finish();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("mPicture FileNotFoundException", e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("mPicture IOException", e.toString());
    }
}

private File getOutputMediaFile() {

    File mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "data"
            + File.separator + context.getPackageName() + File.separator
            + "files" + File.separator + "image.jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Log.e("Tab", "Stoping");

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        return true;

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

}

Help me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Use can use UniversalImageLoader. It do the job for you : download, storing, caching, resizing ... etc

Comment: Take image, Process it and then load it in memory. Try to modify your onPictureTaken Method

Comment: i have already a similar question on SO at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255572/android-bitmap-cache-takes-a-lot-of-memory/18255693#18255693

Answer (score 0):

Can have a look on this
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

Comment: But i have to use decodebytearray,in that case what can i do?