# Issue converting URI to Bitmap (2014):

Tags: android, image, bitmap

In short, I'm trying to select an image from a phone gallery to display as a bitmap to be played with (get average RGB) in another activity.

First thing, I've come across a couple topics dealing with URI to Bitmap conversion.  A lot of them have suggestions like (from: [Retrieve bitmap from uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782713/retrieve-bitmap-from-uri)):

```
    Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
    Imageview my_img_view = (Imageview ) findViewById (R.id.my_img_view);
    my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The Bitmap line is the important line.  Whenever I run my Android app on my simulator, the app crashes (debugger in Eclipse confirms in happens on the URI --> Bitmap conversion line), and if I put the conversion in different activities (it is Bundled), then it still crashes on the Uri -> Bitmap conversion line.

I'm not sure why this is.  I've tried making my intent both "EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" and "INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" on the initial intent, and either choice doesn't matter.  I'm going to keep looking for potential solutions to my problem, but I'm short on time right now and I feel it would be helpful if I had some advice from outside sources.

Anyone know why it always crashes on that line, or if there are any possible solutions to my problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Please get inputstream from the uri

```
Uri IMAGE_URI = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(IMAGE_URI);
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream );
```

Start intent

```
private static final int REGUEST_CODE = 100;
Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REGUEST_CODE);
```

GET THE RESULT

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
switch(requestCode) { 
case REGUEST_CODE :
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri IMAGE_URI = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(IMAGE_URI);
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream );
        my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i think this will help full every one

Answer (score 3):

```
Uri imageUri = intent.getData(); Uri IMAGE_URI = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(IMAGE_URI);

Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream );



Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REGUEST_CODE);
```

GET THE RESULT

```
Uri IMAGE_URI = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(IMAGE_URI);
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream);
my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

How big is the Bitmap you're trying to pass? Can you copy/paste the error message you're getting?

One possible reason for your app crashing is that the data you can pass in main memory from one activity to another is capped in size. I believe the maximum data is about 1-2 MB, depending on the hardware and OS version, although I can't find a reference.