# resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri on Camera

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera, uri

I'm having troubles while trying to create a bitmap from a Camera AND an Image Picker.

I used a code that creates an Uri by the Camera so I added a condition to my function that already load pics from gallery.
Here is the onActivityResult :

```
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE || requestCode == RESULT_CAMERA) {
            Uri selectedImage = null;
            if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE)
            {
                selectedImage = data.getData();
            }
            else if(requestCode == RESULT_CAMERA)
            {
                selectedImage = imageUri;
            }
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                imgViewScan.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                try {
                    InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                            selectedImage);
                    bitmapLoaded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ScanAc", e.toString());
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

and here is the onClick for the Camera :

```
View.OnClickListener takePicture = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
        //create parameters for Intent with filename
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image capture by camera");
        //imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage (also in onSaveInstanceState)
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        //create new Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        Intent i = new Intent(
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_CAMERA);
    }
};
```

I would like to precise that the gallery image pick works perfectly, the problem is only on the camera...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private void onClickCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
        fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_CAMARA);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_no_camera), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

> try this in your takePicture clickListener

Comment: This solved the problem but I doesn't do exactly what I want. I woud like to also convert the ImageURI in a Bitmap and when I do selectedImage = imageUri, it creates a URI with the good value but it's not converted into a bitmap even if the pic is saved. I guess it's because of my condition in the onActivityResult which is "if resultCode == RESULT_OK" but I don't really know

Comment: Visit this may be your problem solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828808/issue-converting-uri-to-bitmap-2014

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating temporary file like below.
In onOnClick event

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
```

and for onActivityResult

```
File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
```