# Can't set image to ImageView returned by camera

Tags: android, imageview

I want to set the image returned from camera to the CropImageView.
The library used is [this](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper).

The image returned by gallery is properly being set.

But with the image returned by camera, when set with `setImageUri()`, the ImageView is empty although it shows the image's `Uri` in the Log.

This is shown by Log in `onActivityResult`

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.example/cache/pickImageResult.jpeg

When trying to set with `setImageBitmap()`, `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data")` results in `NullPointerException`.

The code is

```
public class ImagePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CropImageView mCropImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_picker);
    Log.d("image picker", "activity created");
    mCropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.cropImageView);

}

/**
 * On load image button click, start pick  image chooser activity.
 */
public void onLoadImageClick(View view) {
    startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntent(), 200);
}

/**
 * Crop the image and set it back to the  cropping view.
 */
public void onCropImageClick(View view) {
    Bitmap cropped = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(500, 500);
    if (cropped != null)
        mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(cropped);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = getPickImageResultUri(data);
        Log.d("image picker", imageUri.toString());

        /*Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(photo );*/

        mCropImageView.setImageUri(imageUri);
    }
}

/**
 * Create a chooser intent to select the  source to get image from.<br/>
 * The source can be camera's  (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) or gallery's (ACTION_GET_CONTENT).<br/>
 * All possible sources are added to the  intent chooser.
 */
public Intent getPickImageChooserIntent() {

    // Determine Uri of camera image to  save.
    Uri outputFileUri = getCaptureImageOutputUri();

    List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    // collect all camera intents
    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        if (outputFileUri != null) {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        }
        allIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // collect all gallery intents
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        allIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // the main intent is the last in the  list so pickup the useless one
    Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
    for (Intent intent : allIntents) {
        if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity")) {
            mainIntent = intent;
            break;
        }
    }
    allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

    // Create a chooser from the main  intent
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Select source");

    // Add all other intents
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

    return chooserIntent;
}

/**
 * Get URI to image received from capture  by camera.
 */
private Uri getCaptureImageOutputUri() {
    Uri outputFileUri = null;
    File getImage = getExternalCacheDir();
    if (getImage != null) {

        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getImage.getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));
    }
    return outputFileUri;
}

/**
 * Get the URI of the selected image from  {@link #getPickImageChooserIntent()}.<br/>
 * Will return the correct URI for camera  and gallery image.
 *
 * @param data the returned data of the  activity result
 */
public Uri getPickImageResultUri(Intent data) {
    boolean isCamera = true;
    if (data != null) {
        String action = data.getAction();
        isCamera = action != null && action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
    return isCamera ? getCaptureImageOutputUri() : data.getData();
}
```

}

Please help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.
The code is taken from [here](http://theartofdev.com/2015/02/15/android-cropping-image-from-camera-or-gallery/).

Comment: Are you getting data in `onActivityResult`

Comment: Yes. Like i wrote, the data is present. Weirdly though, Log in the `onActivityResult ` shows the `Uri`. But `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data")` returns `NullPointerException`.

Comment: just do this `data.getData();` instead of `data.getExtras().get("data")`

Comment: That's not possible. `data.getData()` returns `Uri`. Cant be typecasted to `Bitmap`

Comment: can't you convert Uri to bitmap????

Comment: Just see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717740/2715073) you will get idea how to do it.

Comment: Well, I tried that. Does **NOT** crash. But still the `ImageView` is blank.

Comment: @PratikBorole Added Detailed Description... Please check that

Comment: @Clairvoyant to correct myself now, the data is not present. I misjudged the situation earlier. What should be done?

Comment: @Pratik I am facing the exact same problem right now. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Suniel I didn't find a solution. So I just gave up and ended making the functionality like Zomato. Just upload an image from the gallery.

Comment: @PratikBorole how did you fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

For getting image from camera I am using below code, its working in lollipop also:

```
    private void captureFromCamera()
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                String fileName = String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                fileName += ".jpg";

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);

                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                        "Image capture by camera");

                Uri imageUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                new DevicePreferences().addKey(activity, Constants.IMAGE_URI,
                        imageUri.toString());  // Storing in shared preference and in onActivityResult getting uri from shared preference

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

                startActivityForResult(intent,
                        CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Comment: It works, but not on my Galaxy S4 running 5.0.1. Tried three other phones. Works flawlessly on them.

Comment: No error. Just a blank `ImageView`. And as i previously mentioned, the log shows a valid `Uri`.

Answer (score -1):

Can u replace this code

```
Uri imageUri = getPickImageResultUri(data);
Log.d("image picker", imageUri.toString());
mCropImageView.setImageUri(imageUri);
```

with.. This,

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
path = GetPathFromURI(context, imageUri);
bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**GetPathFromURI**

```
public static String GetPathFromURI(Context context,Uri contentUri) {
        String realPath = "";
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            realPath = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return realPath;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not about cropping. The problem is that the image is not being loaded from the camera.

Cropping happens properly.

Comment: @PratikBorole can u please check this

Comment: So turns out, the `Intent data` from `onActivityResult` is null. 
Because i get `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference` message in log. What do i do?