# How to find the android directory that files are downloaded into it

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-download-manager

i have been making an app which download files from internet and save themon storage i have 2 questions :first how to address it to save them in downlod folder which is the exact address? and second where is this "/data/user/0/com.example.moein.download_kotlin/files/Downloads/file.jpg" directory that it is using now?
here is my code

```
            mainFetch = Fetch.Builder(applicationContext, "Download 1 file")
            .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(1) .
            .enableLogging(true)
            .build()

    //Single enqueuing example
    val request = Request("https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-50kb.jpg",
            applicationContext.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() +"/Downloads/file.jpg")
    request.priority=Priority.HIGH;
    request.networkType=NetworkType.ALL
    request.addHeader("download", "2")

    mainFetch!!.enqueue(request, object : Func<Download> {
        override fun call(t: Download) {

        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,t.file,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //toasts /data/user/0/com.example.moein.download_kotlin/files/Downloads/file.jpg

        }
    }, object : Func<Error> {
        override fun call(t: Error) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> first how to address it to save them in downlod folder which is the
>   exact address?

**Use following:**

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

If you are targetting Andrpid 6.0 and above, remember to request for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to write to this directory and  `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to read from this directory. User needs to grant these permissions,hence you have to implement permission model. You can follow this [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) to implement this.

> second where is this
>   "/data/user/0/com.example.moein.download_kotlin/files/Downloads/file.jpg"
>   directory that it is using now?

This is your application-specific directory. Files saved to this are private to your app, and other apps cannot access them (nor can the user, unless they have root access). This makes internal storage a good place for internal app data that the user doesn't need to directly access.

However I found on Samsung device that ES file explorer can access this directory. But its a mystery how they manage to do it.

Comment: `This is your application-specific directory which is accessible to your app only.` Indeed. So no other app has access. `You can install any file explorer app like ES file explorer to access and view this directory contents`. Nonsense. ES File Explorer has no access. No other app has access.

Comment: `Remember to request for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to write to this directory and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to read from this directory.`. Indeed. And dont forget for Android 6+ to add code to let the user confirm these permissions at runtime.

Comment: @greenapps you should first try it and comment. Some how ES file explorer can access it and export some contents ( Tested on Samsung Galaxy A5, not rooted)

Comment: @greenapps thank you correcting Android 6.0 part. Updated the answer

Comment: Please send me your A5 ;-) And try other devices! And explain what it means if you say `which is accessible to your app only. `.

Comment: Hahaha.. unfortunately you have to buy it from Samsung store :-P Sure. Let me explain.

Comment: Updated the answer you can help me to check. I will test on more devices to check if ES file explorer works the same.

Comment: ES File Explorer is no good reference as its programmers know some tricks to write to unwritable storage.

Comment: Removed its reference.

Comment: No no ... Everybody should know.. Good info.

Comment: Added the info again

Comment: @sagar hey tnx for answer ,i have a question how can i show the picture that i download with this library and saved it into that address?

Comment: You can maintain (in SharedPreference or local variable) the Uri of the file and then whereever you want to load you can follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879992/how-to-get-bitmap-from-an-uri)

Comment: when using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) i get permission denied plz help

Comment: You need to request for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to be able to do that