# How to get bitmap from imagebutton

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have `ImageButton` when click on it gallery will appear for pick an image and send `bitmap` back to show on this `ImageButton`.
But I have to get `bitmap` that has been shown on this ImageButton and then save it into  database as `byte[]`

Comment: when you have to pick the image, then why not use the picked image instead of getting from the image button ?

Comment: just store the bitmap into some variable when you set it to imagebutton. And when you need it, just use a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first get the `bitmap` from the `ImgaeButton`

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

then convert this `bitmap` to `byteArray`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you load image from gallery, you already have the URI reference to it, or you have the bitmap. Hope the following helps

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

Now, if you want to get bitmap from imageButton, you can use

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Refer [How to get Bitmap from an Uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879992/how-to-get-bitmap-from-an-uri)  as well, to know more

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a blob to store an image in sqlite android internal db.

*** below answer is completely copied from [How to store image in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database) - credit goes to answer provider

public void insertImg(int id , Bitmap img ) {

```
    byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function

    insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
    insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

    insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
    insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;

}

 public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

to retrieve a image from db

public Bitmap getImage(int i){

```
String qu = "select img  from table where feedid=" + i ;
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qu, null);

if (cur.moveToFirst()){
    byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);
    cur.close();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
}
if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
    cur.close();
}       

return null ;
}
```