# How to fix deprecated issue in Android Bitmap?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap, deprecation-warning, bitmapdrawable

hi guys someone could help me? i'm stucked with this can't find the answer

```
selectedPhotoUri = data.data

val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)

selectphoto_imageview_register.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
selectPhoto_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
```

Specifically, I get this error:

> 'getBitmap(ContentResolver!, Uri!): Bitmap!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Comment: what exactly is deprecated?

Comment: 'getBitmap(ContentResolver!, Uri!): Bitmap!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Comment: you can check the documentation to see what you should use instead of it. Have you tried?

Comment: where can i find that?

Comment: on the official Android website, for example

Comment: i've tried that. helped nothing.. stuck with this bug for hours. im getting sick of it

Comment: what exactly you tried? how exactly?

Comment: i've been searching on lot of sites. including the android site.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable(android.graphics.Bitmap)

Comment: thanks for the help .but i couldn't fix it..

Comment: have you tried what is said there?

Comment: yes man, i've read whole page tried everything ..

Comment: show what you tried and which problems you got while trying

Comment: can we talk in messenger?

Comment: That is not how StackOverflow works. Please keep the discussion here. Edit your question, and add the code that you have tried.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `ImageDecoder#createSource(ContentResolver, Uri)` in place of `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ContentResolver, Uri)` when `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29`. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Also see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder.html#createSource(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri) .

Comment: did you checked this link? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6228188/4057688

Answer (score 0):

```
val bitmap: Bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val src = ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, imageUri)
    ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(src)
} else {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri)
}
```

You can use this code for getting Bitmap.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)

selectphoto_imageview_register.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

You can use

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(selectedPhotoUri)
       .into(selectphoto_imageview_register)
```