# If i have uri that start with "content://com.google.android.apps" how do i get bitmap from that

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I choose from the android device file and i got uri that start with "content://com.google.android.app" and for some reason i can't make load it into bitmap,

the code

```
public void insertImage(View view) {
        Intent chooseFile;
        Intent intent;
        chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.setType("*/*");
        chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String str = data.getData().toString();
                    String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
                    try {
                        // User content resolver to get uri input stream.
                        InputStream inputStream = 
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                        // Get the bitmap.
                        Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        // Show image bitmap in imageview object.
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
                     }catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    }
                }
                break;
             }
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Bitmap from an Uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879992/how-to-get-bitmap-from-an-uri)

Comment: Your code is ok. What do you mean with `i can't make load it into bitmap,` ?

Comment: when i upload to the imageview, the bitmap is return NULL

Comment: You mean that BitmapFactory.decodeStream() returns null. Yes that happens when the resolution of the choosen image is so high that the bitmap would become too big for available memory. Let the user choose a small image and you will see it.

Comment: i add to the manifest
  android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: @user1800263 Apparently you do not know that if you wanna response to a comment you have to call the commenter using an @<nickname>.

Comment: Make sure you have permission

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                getBitmapFromUri(this, uri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
            }
            break;
    }
}


public static Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        parcelFileDescriptor =
                context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load image.", e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error closing ParcelFile Descriptor");
        }
    }
}
```