# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returning null for special files

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap

I know this question has been asked already, but none of the answers helped me. In my gallery app there are special jpg files that i can not decode. No matter where i copy those files, the method BitmapFactory.decodeFile() always return null

```
 if(file.exists()) {
     // val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(file.inputStream())
     val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
     if (bitmap != null) {
         return bitmap
     }
 }
 createEmptyBitmap()
```

But it must be possible, because other gallery apps can show those jpg files. Is there any alternative for creating a Bitmap from a File in Android?

Comment: If those files are not null, get `Uri`s of the files.
`val uri = Uri.fromFile(your_file)`  then decode bitmaps from the `Uri`s https://stackoverflow.com/a/58008340/8531215

Comment: Thanks, but the method MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, uri) returned this exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaStore.Images.Media.…ext.contentResolver, uri) must not be null

Comment: Make sure that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is granted, if the issue still present, use Glide library instead

Comment: If the resolution of those files is high the bitmap could become too big for available memory. Then null is returned.

Comment: Meanwhile i found out that the images that create the problem seem to be corrupt. The file manager shows me for one of the images the size 5,84MB but the resolution -1 x -1 Pixel, and i can not open them in any editor. But still other apps can show a thumbnail of those images.