# creating file from uri in android 11 - getPath() not working

Tags: android, file, uri, android-11, registerforactivityresult

I want to create a file from uri in the ActivityResultCallback in android 11. I use `uri.getPath()` to convert the incoming uri to a file. but, it won't work in android 11. here is my codes:

```
       private void launchGallery (){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            launcherGallery.launch(intent);
        }
    
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcherGallery = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (data != null) {
                            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                            // ---> getPath() won't work in android 11 <---
                            File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
                            // I don't want to display the image in an ImageView. 
                            // I need a file object to pass it to this method to encrypt it
                            encryptImage(file);
                            
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**so, how can I create a file from uri in android 11?**

Comment: If you get an uri for a file in ActivityResultCallback then there is already a file for that uri. Pretty unclear what you want.

Comment: `uri.getPath() to convert the incoming uri to a file. ` First: that makes no sense. Second that delivers a string with a useless value.

Comment: `// ---> getPath() won't work in android 11 <---` Nor only for Android  11 you get nonsense but also in all other Android versions.

Comment: "I use uri.getPath() to convert the incoming uri to a file. but, it won't work in android 11" -- that has never been reliable. Use the `Uri` itself, such as by passing it to your chosen image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.) to populate an `ImageView`.

Comment: I want to pass the file to a method to encrypt the image. I don't want to display it in an ImageView.

Comment: "I want to pass the file to a method to encrypt the image" -- then use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, as suggested in [the answer from snachmsm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687862/115145).

Answer (score 5):

simply: you can't. if `Uri` would be always a `File` then there would be no purpose of both class existance. `Uri` is a "pointer" to a file, which can be read as `InputStream`

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

you have to read all these bytes and if you REALLY need a `File` then store this data in your apps [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage). if you are shure that this is an image (its declared in calling `Intent`) then you may try to convert this data to `Bitmap`.

edit: I see you've added `encryptImage(..)` method call, so for shure you can read [`Bitmap` "straight from" `Uri`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879992/how-to-get-bitmap-from-an-uri) instead of a `File` without taking users storage space, even for a while

check out such case: note that when you run a file picker `launchGallery()` then inside of it you can switch folders. there is a possibility to pick file from e.g. Google Drive, or if you have installed, other web-storages (OneDrive, Dropbox etc.). you will get an `Uri` as a result, but this isn't a real `File` on local storage. so you can stream it (as through web/network) for reading entirelly, it isn't ready and available at the moment of `result` callback call (just after picking and returning to your app)

btw. such possibility isn't limited to Android 11 and above, it was there way earlier. just handle `Uri` as "pointer", do not assume it is pointing on (local) `File`. in some cases even if user pick local file you will get an `Uri` pointing on it through some `ContentResolver` (so use own for read data), thus this won't be a file path (won't be starting with `file://`)